# Setting a mail forward in Exchange Powershell

Tags: powershell, exchange-server

I want to be able to set an email forward in Exchange Powershell O365

I'm trying

```
Set-Mailbox -Identity emailaddress -DeliverToMailboxAndForward $true -ForwardingSMTPAddress forwardingaddress
```

but getting

> A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name
>   'DeliverToMailboxAndForward'.

Do I need to load a snap-in? I can't find any help about this.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot your $'s my friend

```
Set-Mailbox -Identity $emailaddress -DeliverToMailboxAndForward $true -ForwardingSMTPAddress $forwardingaddress
```

Also something to look out for when using Exchange Online PSSession (and maybe regular Exchange PSSession) is that it uses the JEA functionality of PowerShell. JEA is Just Enough Administration it actually looks at what roles the account used to connect to the PowerShell Session has and it ONLY gives you the commands that account has the roles to do. I'm not sure if it goes to the level of removing parameters from functions you only have partial access to do. For the missing Cmdlet part though I ran into this while beating my head against the wall writing a batch migration utility come to find out SysAdmin never gave me the permission to do batch migration. As soon as They gave me the permission and I imported the PSSession again BAM Cmdlet was there.

Hope that helps.

Comment: emailaddress and forwardingaddress were just meant to be dummies.

Comment: I guess I assumed you already imported the PSSession to your exchange server. If you have MFA enabled you need to launch The Exchange Online PowerShell Module (on a hybrid setup its found under the Hybrid Setup page it's a configure button you click on but you HAVE to do it in IE or Edge as it does an install to your computer as a special PowerShell Host that lets you connect to exchange online with MFA)